# Launcher3 isn't responding error on Android 4.4.2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, launcher

I am constantly getting an error on my Xolo q1010i (Android 4.4.2) saying "Launcher3 isn't responding". It gives me two options: "Wait" and "Close".

It appears when I try to open an application, but not with any specific one; it happens randomly.

I have tried doing a factory reset, but in vain.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: This might sound stupid, but have you tried using a different launcher?

Comment: That would be one way. I'd recommend something easier to start with: Go to *Settings › Apps*, chose the *All* tab, scroll to the Launcher (might be called "HomeScreen" or something similar), open its entry, tap the *Clear Cache* button (quite often the reason for those "ANRs" is some messed-up cache). If that doesn't help, you can also try *Delete Data* in the same place (but then all your Launcher/HomeScreen settings are gone).